# Visual Studio 2017 issue during extension installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

i try to install new extension on visual studio 2017 community
when i go to Menu Tool>>Extensions and Updates..
i got error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {xxx} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

I used ProcessMonitor To find missing DLL, I found that "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\x86\Microsoft.Vi‌​sualStudio.Setup.Con‌​figuration.Native.dl‌​l" 
Result:PATH NOT FOUND 
How to resolve this issue ?

Notes:this occur when uninstall VS 2017 RC and Install VS 2017. 
[image]

Comment: 0x8007007E =  ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND, the GUID is the [SetupConfigurationClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.setup.configuration.setupconfigurationclass(v=vs.150).aspx). Use ProcessMonitor to see which DLL (dependecy) is missing

Comment: Thank you for help, i used ProcessMonitor
I found C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\x86\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Native.dll

Result:PATH NOT FOUND

How resolve it?

Comment: run VS2017 installer and repair VS2017

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25294/tools-extensions-and-updates-gives-error-retrievin.html), you should first execute *"InstallCleanup.exe -full" command*, and then run the *Visual Studio Installer* to repair your VS installation.

Comment: InstallCleanup.exe -full completely uninstalled visual studio, so there was nothing to repair.